# Efficient data pattern to store three related items for easy access

Tags: c#

I am having a little trouble designing an efficient data storage method of storing some bookmark elements for a word automation project. Here is what i need to do. I need to get all the bookmarkstart and bookmark end and the bookmark id stored in a neat data structure that lets me access any one of these three objects given one of them with the least runtime complexity. If for example i didnt need the id to be stored, i could just make a dictionary and use the bookmark start as a key and the bookmark end as a value to have an access time of O(1). But is there a logical, simple and efficient structure to have this functionalty with all three of these items coupled together?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be great to have [`Boost.MultiIndex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) in .Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at implementing a customized Map/Hash/Dictionary class for this purpose.

Basically:

```
class BookmarkObj { /* similar to steven's */ }
class BookmarkStore {
 Dictionary<int, BookmarkObj> byId;
 Dictionary<DateTime, BookmarkObj> byStartDate;
 Dictionary<DateTime, BookmarkObj> byEndDate;

 /* Boring init code */

 public void Insert(BookmarkObj obj) {
  byId[obj.Id] = obj;
  byStartDate[obj.Start] = obj;
  byEndDate[obj.End] = obj;
 }

 public BookmarkObj GetById(int id) {
  return byId[obj.Id];
 }

 /* And so on */
```

}

This data structure doesn't really map onto IDictionary, but you could maybe make it implement ICollection if iteration, and contracts are important to you.

If the O(1) lookup is not sooo important, you could alternatively just implement this as an List and do lookups using LINQ and simplify your life a bit. Remember, premature optimization is bad.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a DTO:

```
public class Bookmark
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

You can store those bookmarks in a dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Bookmark>();

dict[bookmark.Id] = bookmark;
```

Comment: the trouble is that i need to store multiple bookmark objects. So if i use a class to construct them, i need to store them in a list of some time which means iterating them is O(n)

Answer (score 2):

If bookmark start and bookmark end are both zero based integers, you could store them in simple arrays.  If you use a dictionary, then it's no longer O(1), but very close to it.

Create a basic object with the 3 fields, then have 2 arrays as indices to the actual data.

```
public class Bookmark
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}

    // setting up your bookmark indices
    const int NumBookmarks = 200;
    Bookmark[] startIndices = new Bookmark[NumBookmarks];
    Bookmark[] endIndices = new Bookmark[NumBookmarks];

    // add a new bookmark
    Bookmark myBookmark = new Bookmark(){ID=5, Start=10, End=30};
    startIndices[myBookmark.Start] = myBookmark;
    endIndices[myBookmark.End] = myBookmark;

    // get a bookmark
    Bookmark myBookmark = startIndices[10];
```

Of course using an array is probably the least flexible, but will be the fastest.

If you don't need absolute speed, you can create a `List`, and use the `Find` method.

```
Bookmark myBookmark = myBookmarks.Find(x=>x.Start==10);
```